# How can I take the lowest value in this code?

Tags: python, database

how are you?
I'm trying to take the lowest value of the following code, my idea is that for example the result will be like. country,price,date

im using python for the code

```
valores= ["al[8075]['2019-05-27']", "de[2177]['2019-05-27']", "at[3946]['2019-05-27']", "be[3019]['2019-05-26']", "by[5741]['2019-05-27']", "ba[0]['2019-05-26', '2019-05-27']", "bg[3223]['2019-05-26']", "hr[4358]['2019-05-26']", "dk[5006]['2019-05-27']", "sk[4964]['2019-05-27']", "si[5253]['2019-05-26']", "es[3813]['2019-05-27']", "ee[4699]['2019-05-27']", "ru[4889]['2019-05-27']", "fi[5410]['2019-05-26']", "fr[2506]['2019-05-26']", "gi[0]['2019-05-26', '2019-05-27']", "gr[1468]['2019-05-26']", "hu[3475]['2019-05-27']", "ie[5360]['2019-05-26']", "is[0]['2019-05-26']", "it[2970]['2019-05-26']", "lv[2482]['2019-05-27']", "lt[1276]['2019-05-27']", "lu[0]['2019-05-26']", "mk[5417]['2019-05-26']", "mt[3532]['2019-05-26']", "md[6158]['2019-05-27']", "me[11080]['2019-05-26']", "no[2967]['2019-05-27']", "nl[3640]['2019-05-27']", "pl[2596]['2019-05-27']", "pt[5409]['2019-05-27']", "uk[5010]['2019-05-27']", "cz[5493]['2019-05-26']", "ro[1017]['2019-05-27']", "rs[6535]['2019-05-27']", "se[3971]['2019-05-26']", "ch[5112]['2019-05-26']", "tr[3761]['2019-05-26']", "ua[5187]['2019-05-26']"]
```

the idea in this example will be like
as you see country(ro) price(1017) date('2019-05-27') is the lowest

valores= "ro[1017]['2019-05-27']"

Comment: The lowest value is decided by all 3 parameters? or just by one or two of them?

Comment: hi @DeveshKumarSingh The lowest value is decided by the price, in this case [ro] has the lowest price [1017] the day ['2019-05-27'] ... others have higher prices. sorry if the price has no sign $. the idea is that the result is valores= "ro[1017]['2019-05-27']"

Comment: but ba has `0` price, why is not that the lowest?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh no no 0 es like null... i want all the prices > to 0

Comment: Understood, check my answer below! It should work for you! @emanuellemos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `max()` and `min()` functions take a key argument. So, whenever you need a minimum or maximum you can often leverage these built-ins. The only code you have to write something to convert a value to the corresponding representation for max/min purposes.

```
def f(s):
    return int(s.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]) or float('inf')

lowest = min(valores, key = f)  # ro[1017]['2019-05-27']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way of coding this. The following will do this:

```
lowest = 1000000
target = " "

for i in valores:
    ix = i.find("[") + 1
    iy = i.find("]")
    value = int(i[ix:iy])
    if value < lowest and value != 0:
        lowest = value
        target = i

print(target)
```

It will output

```
"ro[1017]['2019-05-27]"
```

However, here I am assuming you do not want 0 values, otherwise the answer would be

```
"ba[0]['2019-05-26', '2019-05-27']"
```

If you want to include 0, just modify the if block.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I assume you want the lowest non-zero price.
I split every string in the lists into sublists via square brackets `[` and strip away the extra brackets `[` and `]` for each item, hence each sublist will have `[state, price, dates]` .
I then sort on the price, which is the second item of each sublist, and filter out the `0` prices,

The result will then be the first element of the filtered list

```
import re
import re
valores= ["al[8075]['2019-05-27']", "de[2177]['2019-05-27']", "at[3946]['2019-05-27']", "be[3019]['2019-05-26']", "by[5741]['2019-05-27']", "ba[0]['2019-05-26', '2019-05-27']", "bg[3223]['2019-05-26']", "hr[4358]['2019-05-26']", "dk[5006]['2019-05-27']", "sk[4964]['2019-05-27']", "si[5253]['2019-05-26']", "es[3813]['2019-05-27']", "ee[4699]['2019-05-27']", "ru[4889]['2019-05-27']", "fi[5410]['2019-05-26']", "fr[2506]['2019-05-26']", "gi[0]['2019-05-26', '2019-05-27']", "gr[1468]['2019-05-26']", "hu[3475]['2019-05-27']", "ie[5360]['2019-05-26']", "is[0]['2019-05-26']", "it[2970]['2019-05-26']", "lv[2482]['2019-05-27']", "lt[1276]['2019-05-27']", "lu[0]['2019-05-26']", "mk[5417]['2019-05-26']", "mt[3532]['2019-05-26']", "md[6158]['2019-05-27']", "me[11080]['2019-05-26']", "no[2967]['2019-05-27']", "nl[3640]['2019-05-27']", "pl[2596]['2019-05-27']", "pt[5409]['2019-05-27']", "uk[5010]['2019-05-27']", "cz[5493]['2019-05-26']", "ro[1017]['2019-05-27']", "rs[6535]['2019-05-27']", "se[3971]['2019-05-26']", "ch[5112]['2019-05-26']", "tr[3761]['2019-05-26']", "ua[5187]['2019-05-26']"]

results = []
#Iterate through valores
for item in valores:
    #Extract elements from each string by splitting on [ and then stripping extra square brackets
    items = [it.strip('][')  for it in item.split('[')]
    results.append(items)

#Sort on the second element which is price, and filter prices with are 0
res = list(
    filter(lambda x: int(x[1]) > 0,
    sorted(results, key=lambda x:int(x[1])))
)

#This is your lowest non-zero price
print(res[0])
```

The output will be

```
['ro', '1017', "'2019-05-27'"]
```